# How to get the last characters in a String in Java, regardless of String size

Tags: java, string

I'm looking for a way to pull the last characters from a String, regardless of size. Lets take these strings into example:

```
"abcd: efg: 1006746"
"bhddy: nshhf36: 1006754"
"hfquv: nd: 5894254"
```

As you can see, completely random strings, but they have 7 numbers at the end. How would I be able to take those 7 numbers?

Edit:

I just realized that `String[] string = s.split(": ");` would work great here, as long as I call string[2] for the numbers and string[1] for anything in the middle.

Comment: Both your question and several answers mention `String.split()`, but it is worth noting that `s.split(": ")` is going to compile a new `java.uitl.regex.Pattern` every time you call it, then match your string with that pattern, creating a regex `Matcher` and an `ArrayList` before the `String[]` that is returned. It will be relatively slow and will allocate far more than necessary to solve this problem. Whether this matters depends on the nature of your application. I generally avoid `split()` unless I really need it. (Note that `split()` does _not_ use regex if you split on a single character.)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Lots of things you could do.

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

will get everything after the last colon.

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

everything after the last space.

```
String numbers[] = s.split("[^0-9]+");
```

splits off all sequences of digits; the last element of the numbers array is probably what you want.

Comment: One serendipitous aspect of the `lastIndexOf` approach is that if there *aren't* any spaces, `lastIndexOf` will return -1, so you'll end up with the whole string (`s.substring(0)`).

Comment: s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);

I would like to use that, but how would I be able to get the letters after the first colon? Wouldn't it be s.indexOf(":", 1)?

Answer (score 163):

How about:

```
String numbers = text.substring(text.length() - 7);
```

That assumes that there *are* 7 characters at the end, of course. It will throw an exception if you pass it "12345". You could address that this way:

```
String numbers = text.substring(Math.max(0, text.length() - 7));
```

or

```
String numbers = text.length() <= 7 ? text : text.substring(text.length() - 7);
```

Note that this still isn't doing any validation that the resulting string contains numbers - and it will still throw an exception if `text` is null.

Comment: Very cool......

Answer (score 76):

This question is the top Google result for "Java String Right".

Surprisingly, no-one has yet mentioned Apache Commons [**StringUtils.right()**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#right(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
String numbers = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.right( text, 7 );
```

This also handles the case where `text` is null, where many of the other answers would throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: I wonder too. This way is much more safe than handling all possible problems.

Comment: This is also the only answer that works if you want/need a single expression to safely convert something to a string and get up to the last `n` characters. For example, you could do `StringUtils.right(Objects.toString(someObj), 7)`.

Answer (score 26):

This code works for me perfectly:

```
String numbers = text.substring(Math.max(0, text.length() - 7));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve it using this single line **code :**

```
String numbers = text.substring(text.length() - 7, text.length());
```

But be sure to **catch Exception if the input string length is less than 7**.

You can replace 7 with any number say N, if you want to get last 'N' characters.

Comment: It's better to check in advance whether the input length is 7 or longer, and then do the substring.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use either `String.split` or a regex:

---

**Using String.split**

```
String[] numberSplit = yourString.split(":") ; 
String numbers = numberSplit[ (numberSplit.length-1) ] ; //!! last array element
```

---

**Using RegEx** (requires `import java.util.regex.*`)

```
String numbers = "" ;
Matcher numberMatcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7}").matcher(yourString) ;
    if( matcher.find() ) {
            numbers = matcher.group(0) ;
    }
```

Comment: Regex should be `[0-9]{7}$` to make sure it matches the **last** 7 digits.

Comment: @ Willi Schönborn: Agreed. The OP's case suggested that the other groups in the string would always contain letters. I was assuming that it was unnecessary to specify a boundary.

Answer (score 3):

```
String inputstr = "abcd: efg: 1006746"
int startindex = inputstr.length() - 10;
String outputtendigitstr = inputstr.substring(startindex);
```

Make sure you check string length is more than 10.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 Integer i= Integer.parseInt(text.substring(text.length() - 7));
```

Answer (score 1):

StringUtils.substringAfterLast("abcd: efg: 1006746", ": ")   = "1006746";

As long as the format of the string is fixed you can use **substringAfterLast**.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substring(s, -7)
```

gives you the answer. It returns the input if it is shorter than 7, and null if s == null. It never throws an exception.

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring-java.lang.String-int-int-

Answer (score 0):

E.g : "abcd: efg: 1006746"
"bhddy: nshhf36: 1006754"
"hfquv: nd: 5894254"

-Step 1: `String firstString =  "abcd: efg: 1006746";`

-Step 2: `String lastSevenNumber = firstString.substring(firstString.lastIndexOf(':'), firstString.length()).trim();`