# String Manipulation in Java: split string after numbers

Tags: java, string

My string have this form XxYxZx

X , Y and  Z are characters and the x are numbers which can vary from 0-999.

I want to split this string in this form. How can this be done?

1. Xx
2. Yx
3. Zx

**Example:**

```
 Input:  "A155B45C77D89" 
 Output: "A155", "B45", "C77", "D89"
```

Comment: can you explain exactlay what is your input and what you want output?

Comment: duplicate link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243721/how-to-get-the-last-characters-in-a-string-in-java-regardless-of-string-size

Comment: @Andrew, I believe the question is "how do I split a string on the form `XxYxZx` into `Xx`, `Yx`, `Zx`".

Comment: @aioobe  I believe in Goblins.  But that is as relevant to what the OP's actual (as yet unstated) question is, as speculation.  (And questions need a '?')  ;)

Comment: Hehe.. If the guy says, *"I want to do this... but I don't know how."* can you seriously not figure out what he is "asking"?

Answer (score 7):

```
String myString="A155B45C77D89";
String[] parts = myString.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\p{Alpha})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[A155, B45, C77, D89]
```

---

**Explanation:**

`String.split` works with regular expressions. The regular expression `(?<=\d)(?=\p{Alpha})` says "match all substrings *preceeded by a digit, succeeeded by a alphabetic character*.

In a string such as `"A155B45C77D89"`, this expression is matched by **the empty** substrings

```
A155 B45 C77 D89
    ^   ^   ^
  here  |   |
       here |
            |
        and here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([A-Z])([0-9]+)" );
        Matcher m = p.matcher( "X01Y123Z99" );
        while ( m.find() ) {
            System.out.println( m.group( 1 ) + " " + m.group( 2 ) );
        }
    }
```

prints

```
X 01
Y 123
Z 99
```