# Counting the length of the textbox

Tags: netbeans-8

I want to try that if they input only two characters in the first name, it will also display, because only three characters and up is readable. thanks

```
String first = "";
String lnm = "";
String num = "";
String stud = "";
int num1;
int num2;
int id;

String fname = request.getParameter("name");
String lname = request.getParameter("last");
String Sid = request.getParameter("num");

first = fname.substring(fname.length()-3);
lnm = lname.substring(0, 3);

num1 = Integer.parseInt(Sid.substring(0, 2));
num2 = Integer.parseInt(Sid.substring(Sid.length()-6));

id = num2/num1;
stud = Integer.toString(id);

out.println(first + lnm + stud.substring(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link which has a solution to a similar problem and I think it will solve your problem as well: [How to get the last characters in a String in Java, regardless of String size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243721/how-to-get-the-last-characters-in-a-string-in-java-regardless-of-string-size)

Jon Skeet responded to that post with 3 different possible solutions. His second solution should solve your problem as well:

```
String numbers = text.substring(Math.max(0, text.length() - 7));
```

In your case this would be:

```
first=fname.substring(Math.max(0, fname.length()-3));
```

I hope that helps.